# Is it possible to use OWIN to manage only the user login and logout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

I'd like to use authentication in `MVC5` the same way I used in `MVC4` `FormsAuthenticaiton.SignIn(...)`, but I don't want to use Forms Auth. After OWIN was set as standard I read in a lot of places how it was safer and all that.

So what I mean by "the same way" is being able to just call a method and say the user is logged in or log the user out the same way, like `FormsAuthentication.SignIn` and `FormsAuthentication.SignOut`.

I don't want to customize OWIN's application user because I don't expose my POCO to my Web project and even less my DbContext (that's also heavily customized). All I want is to use OWIN, but just to manage the user session states (login, session, timeout, logout) I don't need, nor want OWIN's Roles, User and so forth.

I hope I was clear, if not please tell me what's unclear so I can try to improve it.

I appreciate any help, this thing is bugging me! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after much code inspection and thanks to ReSharper's decompiler I was able to figure it out. 
This is my working code:

```
public static IAuthenticationManager GetAuthenticationManager(this Controller controller)
{
    return controller.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
}

public static void SignIn(this Controller controller, string username, string fullName, bool isPersistent = false)
{
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, null);

    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username, ClaimValueTypes.String));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, fullName, ClaimValueTypes.String));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("LastLogin", DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)));

    controller.GetAuthenticationManager().SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}

public static void SignOut(this Controller controller)
{
    controller.GetAuthenticationManager().SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
}
```

What I did was create an extension class with these methods above and use it on my Controller, I just call the methods SignIn and SignOut. The "secret"/answer is:

- Retrieve the IAuthenticationManager
- Create a ClaimsIdentity with the login information I wanted
- Sign in using the IAuthenticationManager and the ClaimsIdentity

That was it. =/